# Проблема с UPDATE в MySql

Tags: update, mysql

```
UPDATE  `user1734_monty`.`tasks` SET  `tstop` =  '1' WHERE  `tasks`.`tedit` DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 HOUR) > tedit;
```

Вообщем обновляют записи, у которых tedit больше 5 часов, но запрос ругается на **DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 HOUR)**

Как быть?

Comment: Блин.

     WHERE  `tasks`.`tedit` DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 HOUR) > tedit

Что это может значить?

Comment: `tasks`.`tedit` - это как-то лишнее )).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
UPDATE  `user1734_monty`.`tasks` SET  `tstop` =  '1' WHERE tedit < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 HOUR);
```